# "replacement has length zero" error using an edf() command after a gamlss

Tags: r, gam

I am working on a database of 44000 newborns, with only two variables:
`gestational age at birth in weeks` and `bmi`.
no blanks.

I run a `gamlss`:

```
gamlss.males <- gamlss(bmi2clean ~ cs(sapp), family = BCPE, data = bmimales)
```

and everything seems to work well: 
I got the centile curves and the centiles predictions.
and later I tried to obtain the edf of the parameters, like this:

```
edf(gamlss.males, what = c("mu", "sigma", "nu", "tau"), print=TRUE)
```

or like this:

```
edfAll(gamlss.males)
```

and always get the following error:

```
Error in edf[i] <- x[[i]]$edf : replacement has length zero
```

cannot figure out why.
I would really appreciate you help!

Comment: is `x[[i]]$edf` NULL?

Comment: I cannot figure it out. it tells me 'x' is not an object. but I can add that I tried all parameters, one by one and got that error only for the mu. While for the other parameters I get: 
Effective df for nu model 
numeric(0)
Effective df for sigma model 
numeric(0)

Effective df for tau model 
numeric(0)

Comment: Isn't it strange that all parameters are zero and mu gives an error? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: youre only supposed to select one in `edf`: `edf(mod, what = "sigma", print=TRUE)`. the example in `?edfAll` works for me, but using `edfAll` on the example under `?gamlss` doesn't work. I don't have your data so I cant say what will work for you

Comment: now, if I change the model with the following: gamlss.males <- gamlss(bmi2clean ~ pb(sapp), family = BCPE, data = bmimales, method=RS())
where cs was changed to pb, I then get: > edfAll(gamlss.males)
$mu
pb(sapp) 
10.59411 

$sigma
numeric(0)

$nu
numeric(0)

$tau
numeric(0)
which is still strange: now I got mu, but all other parameters are "numeric(0)"